# CKEDITOR is not defined in CKEditor5

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I installed `CKEditor` library to my web project and it's working fine. But as I saw on SO, to change a configuration, I need to use the `CKEDITOR` class.

So when I use this code:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
    extraAllowedContent: 'style;*[id,rel](*){*}'
});
```

I get an error in my console saying

> Uncaught ReferenceError: CKEDITOR is not defined

But without the above code, the library works fine. Is there anything I'm not getting right?

Here is my full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>CKEditor</title>
        <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/38.1.1/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="editor">This is some sample content.</div>
        <script>
            ClassicEditor
                .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) )
                .then( editor => {
                    console.log( editor );
                })
                .catch( error => {
                    console.error( error );
                });

            CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
                extraAllowedContent: 'style;*[id,rel](*){*}'
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay... So the `CKEDITOR` class is no longer supported in version 5+

So I got a way to implement what I wanted. Which is to allow CKEDITOR to accept the `style` HTML element.

From this [Documentation](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/html/general-html-support.html), I used the code below

```
ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
        // List of HTML Elements to be allowed
        htmlSupport: {
            allow: [
                {
                    name: /.*/,     // Allows all element
                    attributes: true,       // Allows all attributes
                    classes: true,      // Allows all classes
                    styles: true        // Allows all inline-css styles
                }
            ]
        }
    })
    .then( editor => {
        window.editor = editor;
    })
    .catch( err => {
        console.error( err.stack );
    });
```